# .fbx imported in Blender won't show up in rendered image

Tags: rendering, mesh, .fbx, blend-files

I imported a .fbx Lavender plant and vase into blender. I scale it up and go ahead to render. In its rendered image, only the vase is displayed, the plant itself is no where to be found.

What I have tried to do:

1. Scale up mesh and re-render. Same outcome.
2. Parent plant to vase and re-render. Same outcome.
3. Scale up mesh & Apply All Transformation, and re-render. Same outcome.

What I realised:

1. After I increased scale of plant and vase from (1 to 10), I save the imported .fbx file as a blend file.
2. I opened the .blend file and realised that the vase stayed at scale 10, while the plant went back to scale 1.

Meaning, while I may not have seen the plant in the rendered image, I think it is still there inside the vase. I just cannot not see it as it did not increase in scale as the vase.[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's visible in the Outliner, that you have some animation. That is probably the cause. The object has a keyframe with some property that makes it not visible in the render(location, scale, visibility...) and it comes back to it during rendering or when loading the file.

[image]

You should select the object(s) with animation and search( <kbd>F3</kbd> ) for Remove Animation operator:

[image]

It's also in 3D Viewport header menu - Object -> Animation -> Clear Keyframes

Comment: Thank you very much. I have removed the key frame. The render is perfect.